# Open Ports on iPhone?

Tags: internet, apache-http-server, iphone

I host a small, personal Apache server on my desktop and allow others to visit it using my IP address. If I normally have a connection which runs through a router (allowing me to specify which ports to allot where, etc.), how can I have the same functionality when I'm using my iPhone for my internet connection? I want to be able to visit the IP my iPhone is given on a browser like I normally can when I am on a regular connection. Thanks!

Comment: It appears [doable](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/run-a-lightweight-webserver-on-your-idevice.326838/), but I don't know that I'd recommend it; you'll first need to jailbreak your phone, which risks voiding any warranty it has.

Comment: Not if I bring it to the store factory restored.. hehehe >:) they'll never even begin to have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to know your current IP address, right?

If you google for "whats my ip" Google actually shows your external ip address; alternatively, use www.whatismyip.com . You can find the network-internal adress (if on wlan) under Settings>WiFi>Blue Arrow next to your network.

Maybe this is already enough for you to work with, otherwise, what is the end goal? Maybe we can find another solution.

Comment: Not quite. I appreciate the assistance but I meant how can I simply host a server on an iPhone (preferably Apache)? When I try to visit, as you pointed out how to locate, the IP address of the phone, there is no response even when I am running a jailbroken distribution of Apache. Basically: are ports the issue here or what?